# VSCode PHP debug in Launch currently open script that breakpoint cannot work

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I use PHP debug of VSCode in the Launch currently open script mode.
When I use breakpoint to stop my PHP script, it will go to the end of my script.

These are my settings and my code:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Good rule of thumb, try to use actual code instead of code in picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the answer. If we want to debug in the cli mode, we have to configure xdebug in the /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini. Previously, I just set /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini!

It is my setting:

[image]